# Ordering lexer rules in a grammar using ANTLR4

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4, lexer

I'm using ANTLR4 to generate a parser.  I am new to parser grammars.  I've read the very helpful [ANTLR Mega Tutorial](https://tomassetti.me/antlr-mega-tutorial/) but I am still stuck on how to properly order (and/or write) my lexer and parser rules.

I want the parser to be able to handle something like this:

Hello << name >>, how are you?

At runtime I will replace "<< name >>" with the user's name.

So mostly I am parsing text words (and punctuation, symbols, etc), except with the occasional "<< something >>" tag, which I am calling a "func" in my lexer rules.

Here is my grammar:

```
doc: item* EOF ;
item: (func | WORD) PUNCT? ;
func: '<<' ID '>>' ;

WS : [ \t\n\r] -> skip ;
fragment LETTER : [a-zA-Z] ;
fragment DIGIT : [0-9] ;
fragment CHAR : (LETTER | DIGIT | SYMB ) ;
WORD : CHAR+ ;
ID: LETTER ( LETTER | DIGIT)* ;
PUNCT : [.,?!] ;
fragment SYMB : ~[a-zA-Z0-9.,?! |{}<>] ;
```

Side note: I added "PUNCT?" at the end of the "item" rule because it is possible, such as in the example sentence I gave above, to have a comma appear right after a "func".  But since you can also have a comma after a "WORD" then I decided to put the punctuation in "item" instead of in both of "func" and "WORD".

If I run this parser on the above sentence, I get a parse tree that looks like this:
[image: Parse tree 1]

Anything highlighted in red is a parse error.

So it is not recognizing the "ID" inside the double angle brackets as an "ID".  Presumably this is because "WORD" comes first in my list of lexer rules.  However, I have no rule that says "<< WORD >>", only a rule that says "<< ID >>", so I'm not clear on why that is happening.

If I swap the order of "ID" and "WORD" in my grammar, so now they are in this order:

```
ID: LETTER ( LETTER | DIGIT)* ;
WORD : CHAR+ ;
```

And run the parser, I get a parse tree like this:
[image: Parse tree 2]

So now the "func" and "ID" rules are being handled appropriately, but none of the "WORD"s are being recognized.

How do I get past this conundrum?

I suppose one option might be to change the "func" rule to "<< WORD >>" and just treat everything as words, doing away with "ID".  But I wanted to differentiate a text word from a variable identifier (for instance, no special characters are allowed in a variable identifier).

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I am not an ANTLR user, but I believe ANTLR works the same way as other parser generators that I've used: Tokens are recognized with no regard to the grammar from top to bottom. So if something matches both `WORD` and `ID`, say, it will always be recognized as the token defined first in the grammar definition. So yes, you probably need a common token definition that you use in both places. You can check after parsing that the characters used match the requirement for the production.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [The Definitive ANTLR 4 Reference](https://pragprog.com/book/tpantlr2/the-definitive-antlr-4-reference) :

> ANTLR resolves lexical ambiguities by
>   matching the input string to the rule specified first in the grammar.

With your grammar (in Question.g4) and a t.text file containing

```
Hello << name >>, how are you at nine o'clock?
```

the execution of

```
$ grun Question doc -tokens -diagnostics t.text
```

gives

```
[@0,0:4='Hello',<WORD>,1:0]
[@1,6:7='<<',<'<<'>,1:6]
[@2,9:12='name',<WORD>,1:9]
[@3,14:15='>>',<'>>'>,1:14]
[@4,16:16=',',<PUNCT>,1:16]
[@5,18:20='how',<WORD>,1:18]
[@6,22:24='are',<WORD>,1:22]
[@7,26:28='you',<WORD>,1:26]
[@8,30:31='at',<WORD>,1:30]
[@9,33:36='nine',<WORD>,1:33]
[@10,38:44='o'clock',<WORD>,1:38]
[@11,45:45='?',<PUNCT>,1:45]
[@12,47:46='<EOF>',<EOF>,2:0]
line 1:9 mismatched input 'name' expecting ID
line 1:14 extraneous input '>>' expecting {<EOF>, '<<', WORD, PUNCT}
```

Now change `WORD` to `word` in the `item` rule, and add a `word` rule :

```
item: (func | word) PUNCT? ;
word: WORD | ID ;
```

and put ID before WORD :

```
ID: LETTER ( LETTER | DIGIT)* ;
WORD : CHAR+ ;
```

The tokens are now

```
[@0,0:4='Hello',<ID>,1:0]
[@1,6:7='<<',<'<<'>,1:6]
[@2,9:12='name',<ID>,1:9]
[@3,14:15='>>',<'>>'>,1:14]
[@4,16:16=',',<PUNCT>,1:16]
[@5,18:20='how',<ID>,1:18]
[@6,22:24='are',<ID>,1:22]
[@7,26:28='you',<ID>,1:26]
[@8,30:31='at',<ID>,1:30]
[@9,33:36='nine',<ID>,1:33]
[@10,38:44='o'clock',<WORD>,1:38]
[@11,45:45='?',<PUNCT>,1:45]
[@12,47:46='<EOF>',<EOF>,2:0]
```

and there is no more error. As the -gui graphic shows, you have now branches identified as `word` or `func`.

Answer (score 1):

As "500 - Internal Server Error" already mentioned in his comment ANTLR will match lexer rules in the order they are defined in the grammar (the topmost rule will be matched first) and if a certain input has been matched ANTLR won't try to match it differently.

In your case the `WORD` and `ID` rule can both match input like `abc` but as `WORD` is declared first `abc` will always be matched as a `WORD` and never as an `ID`. In fact `ID` will never be matched as there is no valid input as an `ID` that can not be matched by `WORD`.

However if your only goal is to replace whatever is in between `<<` and `>>` you'd be better off using regular expressions. However if you still want to use ANTLR for it you should reduce your grammar to only care about the essentials. That is to distinguish between any input and input in between `<<` and `>>`. Therefore your grammar should look something like this:

```
start: (INTERESTING | UNINTERESTING) ;
INTERESTING: '<<' .*? '>>' ;
UNINTERESTING: (~[<])+ | '<' ;
```

Or you could skip the `UNINTERESTING` completely.